# Insert/Delete row animations with transparent section view

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8

I'm implementing Apple's section expanding TalbleViewSection example, which can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html). When my section background is transparent deleting or inserting cells with `UITableViewRowAnimationTop` and `UITableViewRowAnimationBottom` causes something like this:

[image: row goes below section]

Probably it is not about sections, same thing will happen with `UITableViewCell` too. Question is, How am I going to make the row disappear before it collides with the section?

Comment: Suggestion: if section is collapsed, then don't do any animations, just replace the dataSource array and reload table.

Comment: It's just a question. UITableViewRowAnimationFade works well

Comment: If you require then give pass 0 as numberOfRowsInSection method on your condition, hence, it will not load any cell to that section.

Comment: provide your code for expand collapse button

Comment: It is on the question (check the link). The question is about Apple's tutorial. Only with transparent section background